Can I add my custom File Upload field as email attachment? (Flexible Checkout Fields PRO WooCommerce)
I don't know why, but uploaded files are attached, when the customer gets the mail, but not when the shopadmin gets it, that's why I tried this code. For single files, it works, but to for more than one file.
The check for Display On > Pages/Emails > Emails is set.
add_filter('woocommerce_email_attachments', 'add_flexible_checkout_fields_attachments_to_vendor_email', 10, 3);

function add_flexible_checkout_fields_attachments_to_vendor_email($attachments, $email_id, $order) {
    if ($email_id === 'new_order') {
        $order_id = $order->get_id();
        $uploaded_files = get_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_datei_upload', true);
        if (!empty($uploaded_files)) {
            if (is_string($uploaded_files)) {
                $uploaded_files = explode(',', $uploaded_files);
            }
            if (is_array($uploaded_files)) {
                foreach ($uploaded_files as $file) {
                    $file_path = get_attached_file($file);
                    if ($file_path && file_exists($file_path)) {
                        $attachments[] = $file_path; 
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $file_path = get_attached_file($uploaded_files);
                if ($file_path && file_exists($file_path)) {
                    $attachments[] = $file_path;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $attachments;
}

I tried multiple versions of this code, but can't find the error and the docs from Flexible Checkout Fields PRO WooCommerce don't help.

Note that since version 3, WooCommerce is progressively migrating to custom database tables for better performances, so you should always better use available methods, especially with WooCommerce orders when High Performance Order Storage is enabled (now enabled by default), instead of using WordPress Post meta functions…  Try to use: $uploaded_files = $order->get_meta('_billing_datei_upload');, even if it doesn't solve your issue.
